# Fully enumerate a generator to a string in JavaScript 1.7

Tags: javascript, generator

Given a generator I would like to create a string from a complete enumeration of it.

I would like something terser than:

```
var s = '';
for(var i in generator) {
 s += i;
}

return s;
```

Ideally I would like a single line equivalent. Does it exist?

Comment: You'll need to be a little more specific about what a "generator" is here; it's not a native JavaScript concept.

Comment: I am talking about JavaScript generators implemented using the `yield` keyword in JavaScript 1.7. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry. I'm living in the past :)